# Object: Tool or environment <> not found error randomly occured in a custom Toolbox used in a Python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arctoolbox

I have developed a custom toolbox on ArcGIS 10.1. It has the following properties:

```
Name: SingleFDI
Label: SingleFDI
Alias: FFDI
```

In a Python script, I used `arcpy.ImportToolbox` to call a tool named `FBFDRwMFDI` in the toolbox.

```
TOOL_BOX_FILE_DIR = r'D:/aaa_workspace/SingleFDI/Models/SingleFDI.tbx'
arcpy.ImportToolbox(TOOL_BOX_FILE_DIR)
model_result = arcpy.FBFDRwMFDI_FFDI(r'D:/aaa_workspace/SingleFDI, str(4))
```

I occasionally received the `Object: Tool or environment <FBFDRwMFDI_FFDI> not found` error. This happened roughly once every 5 times.

I am unable to tell why it happened because it was so random!

I read the ArcGIS help document. It states in

> ImportToolbox(input_file, {module_name}),  module_name{String}: If the
>   toolbox does not have an alias, the module_name is required.

I would like to know what the `module_name` stands for in the syntax? Is it meant to be the `Alias` or `Name` property of the Toolbox? I ever tried using the Alias property in the ImportToolbox but the same error was still occuring occasionally and randomly.

Comment: If this is "occuring occasionally and randomly" on the same toolbox and tool, with the same code, then it sounds non-reproducible.